# How to open modal and detch fata using Id dynamically

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

when I click on a link in table, modal will appear but it has no data in it. I want that when I click on a link, modal will appear and show all records fetched by `Id` in `href`.

Here is the table where I fetch my data from:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive" data-toggle="datatables">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Ref No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Contact Person</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $counter = 0;
        $query = mysql_query("select * from notes_mst GROUP BY REF_NO");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {      
            $cust = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '".$row['CUSTOMER_ID']."'");
            $row_cust = mysql_fetch_array($cust);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo ++$counter; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo 'IS - REF NO '.$row['REF_NO']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['DATE']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row_cust['CONTACT_PERSON_NAME']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" href="file.php?id=<?php echo $row['REF_NO'];?>" class="">
                        <span class="color-color-scheme">
                            <i class="list-icon material-icons">remove_red_eye</i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            //Content Will show Here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

file.php

[image]

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#editBox').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you format your code properly, it is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to fetch data on the event when the modal opens
**Please try This**

```
$('#editBox').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#editBox .modal-content').html(<p>Please wait!</p>);
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.php?id=<?php echo $row['REF_NO'];?>",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            $('#editBox .modal-content').html(res);
        }
    });
});
```